# Separator, Comparison, Operator Token Types

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, lexical-analysis

From "Compilers Principles, Techniques, & Tools, 2nd Ed." ("The Purple Book") by Aho, Lam, Sethi and Ullman:

Figure 3.2: Examples of tokens pg. 112

```
[Token]       [Informal Description]                  [Sample Lexemes]
if            characters i, f                         if
else          characters e, l, s, e                   else
comparison    < or > or <= or >= or == or !=          <=, !=
id            letter followed by letters and digits   pi, score, D2
number        any numeric constant                    3.14159, 0, 6.02e23
literal       anything but ", surrounded by "'s       "core dumped"
```

In the above, they separate `if` and `else` into their own token types. In most examples I've seen, these would be a single `keyword` token type and the values of the tokens would be `if` or `else`. What is the benefit of having separate token types for each keyword rather than a `keyword` token type?

What is the benefit of having token types like `comparison`? Why not have a token type for each kind of comparison like the following?

```
[Token]       [Informal Description]                  [Sample Lexemes]
lt            <                                       <
gt            >                                       >
lte           <=                                      <=
gte           >=                                      >=
eq            ==                                      ==
neq           !=                                      !=
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opinions vary about how individual operators are represented when the operators are syntactically identical. Many people will write separate productions for different operators even though there is no real syntactic difference and the semantic difference is limited.

Having said that, there are languages in which `==`, `>=` and `<=` are syntactically distinct. In C (and its family), the precedence of these operators differs making it possible to write `a <= b == b <= c` without parentheses, although code containing that expression is unlikely to survive a code review. (Even with parentheses, the expression is questionable.) In Perl, `a <= b <= c` is a valid cascading comparison, but `a <= b == c` is not. Etc.

The general rule is that if a token has a distinct role in the language syntax, the difference must be visible to the parser, and the parser only takes into account the token's type, not its value. For that reason, `if`, `then` and `else` must be different token types in any practical grammar.

Comment: “and the parser only takes into account the token’s type, not its value.” That seems like a solid rule I need to ponder more. How does the parser convert a string literal token to a string node in the parse tree? I suppose the order doesn’t need to examine the value of the string token to do this conversion. The parser just passes the value to the string node constructor. Is that correct? Thanks.

Comment: @tedhenry: The lexical scanner makes a string literal node, and informs the parser that it has a string literal token. The semantic value itself is passed through the parser, which doesn't care, to the AST constructor or evaluator or compiler or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

## Why to use different token types for keywords

When writing a parser, you usually `switch` on the token type. If the token type isn't enough information to make a decision, that means you also have to check the value of the token inside the `case`. If the token's value is represented as a string, it will also be more expensive to compare (even if the string is interned, a sequence of if-else-if will still be less efficient than a switch). In many parser generators, making decisions based on a token's value is either impossible or more complicated than just using the token's type.

To illustrate this, here is an excerpt of a hand-written parser where different keywords have different token types:

```
parse_statement() {
  switch(current_token.type) {
    case IF:
      parse_if_statement(); break;
    case WHILE:
      parse_while_statement(); break;
    //...
    case ID: case NUMBER: case LITERAL:
      parse_expression_statement(); break;
    default:
      syntax_error(); break;
  }
}
```

And the same code where that's not the case:

```
parse_statement() {
  switch(current_token.type) {
    case KEYWORD:
      if (current_token.value == "if") {
        parse_if_statement();
      } else if (current_token.value == "while") {
        parse_while_statement();
      // '}  else if(...) {'s for other valid keywords go here
      } else {
        syntax_error();
      }
    // Other statement types that don't start with a keyword go here
    case ID: case NUMBER: case LITERAL:
      parse_expression_statement(); break;
    default:
      syntax_error(); break;
  }
}
```

Note the additional nesting and that there are now two places where `syntax_error` is called.

For parser generators it'd look like this with different token types:

```
statement
  : IF condition body (ELSE body)?
  | WHILE condition body
  | ... | expression ';' ;
```

Or like this if there were only a keyword token type:

```
statement
  : if condition body (else body)?
  | while condition body
  | ... | expression ';' ;

if: {current_token.value == "if"} KEYWORD ;
else: {current_token.value == "else"} KEYWORD ;
while: {current_token.value == "while"} KEYWORD ;
```

And that's only for parser generators that support semantic predicates. In many others, this would just not be possible at all.

## Why to use the same token type for comparison operators

When different tokens always appear at the same place in the grammar, that is the grammar makes no distinction between them, it's a convenient shortcut to merge them into a single token type. Again let's compare the grammar with a comparison type vs. individual types:

```
comparison_exp: additive_exp COMPARISON additive_exp ;
```

And with individual types:

```
comparison_exp: additive_exp comparison additive_exp ;
comparison: LT | GT | LTE | GTE | EQ | NEQ;
```

So if you only have one token type, you don't need to spell out all the options in the grammar.

Compared to the first question, this is a more minor and subjective thing though.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. If operators are to be grouped into several token types, it makes sense to group them by precedence? Grouping * and / together in a single token type. Grouping + and - together in a single token type.

Comment: @TedHenry Yes, though it depends on other factors as well. For example `*` can be also used as a prefix operator in some languages and `/` can't - so the two wouldn't be interchangeable. Grouping tokens together also means that you have to change more code if you later change the language in a way that gives an additional meaning to one of the operators, but not the others (like if you group `*` and `/` together and then later add a prefix `*` operator, you have to undo the grouping).

Comment: Based on your explanations, I’ll try using token types so that the parser’s control flow (switch vs if) is as efficient as possible. That is, the lexer’s job is to make tokens that are easy for the parser to use when the parser encounters each token. Makes sense?

Comment: @TedHenry Yes, that makes sense.